# Should Azure DevOps agents clean up file share artifacts

Tags: azure-devops

Should Azure DevOps locally hosted agents be able to clean up file share artifacts?

We have builds that drop to an on-prem file share and these use the default retention policy set on Azure DevOps. Once the retention policy for the build has expired, the build will be clean up as expected but the build artifact will remain in the file share.

I thought this was expected behaviour but there is nothing in the docs that say this is expected behaviour and i have also seen some comments on the MS Developer Community that suggest that the file share artifacts should also be cleaned up.

Was just looking for anyone else's experiences with this

Comment: They should, but there was a bug at one point that prevented it from working. What agent version are you using?

Comment: I'm using cloud version - is there also issue?